# Why can't I blur alacritty terminal emulator with compton?

Tags: i3, terminal-emulator, compton

I am currently using using i3 with arch linux. I just installed alacritty and compton and I have edited the alacritty configuration file to allow for transparency. So now alacritty is now transparent however I want to make it blurry. I tried using the following solution to change my compton configuration file: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243421 . When I rebooted my computer and tried to open a terminal, it was very slow and the blur didn't even work.

Why can't I blur alacritty with this solution? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What fork of compton are you using?